# Batch "resize" JPEG images to a fixed file size

Tags: images, batch

Changing quality of the JPEG when saving an image, changes the file size. For eg. I have the following image. Dimension: 243px x 53 px Quality:100% File Size:9.7kb
Background:

[image: sample image]

[image: size1]

If I edit the image, keeping the dimensions and Quality same, the file size still falls to 6.1kb.

[image: sample 2]

[image: size 2]

Problem: I am using Fotoresizer, which has a batch Quality change option, but due to the above problem, you cannot predict file size from quality alone. So when I batch change quality of a set of 200px x 300px images set at 20% quality, some files will turn out at 6kb, whereas others will turn out at 15kb, when the file size I want is 10kb.

Is there any program or programmable solution, which lets me save all files in a range of 10-11kb, without me manually changing the quality slider to change file size each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDsizer will allow you to do this you can set a maximum file size from the interface and drop a batch of files to resize.

http://www.idimager.com/WP/?page_id=396

Just as an aside, be aware that the quality once you have done this may be quite poor. Also if the image will save at a high quality with out compression some files could be less than 10Kb.

Answer (score 2):

[Irfan View](http://alternativeto.net/software/irfanview/) can convert image to jpeg of Your desired size.

**Preconditions**

If You will not find following option You have to download [Irfan View plugins](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm).

**How to do it in Irfan View?**

You have to press 'b' key or click on "file->batch conversion/rename". Then You can set desired file size of images You want to convert.

[image]

**Notes**

It might take longer to encode it. From what I tested it looks like that compression options are found by compressing image several times and doing binary search to find those which produce Your desired size; I may be wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

[RIOT (Radical Image Optimization Tool)](https://riot-optimizer.com/) was the program I used for such a task. It's free for personal and non-profit usage and extremely easy to use. To batch-convert the images you press "Batch" button, add your images, choose "Additional tasks" -> "Compress to size" option, set desired filesize threshold and start the process. Of course, it takes somewhat longer comparing to the common conversion methods (for me, 7 images were converted in about 1 minute).

This is the screenshot of the tool in process.

[image: screenshot]